# Unwanted bottom-border poping in chrome on hover

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm new here :) Hope i could some help around. i'm pretty new to css and web designing and coding and everything. i'm working on some kind of website project, and i run into a problem. the problem is when I hover a parent div on low screen resolution [800*600], for some reason in google-chrome it shows border bottom for child divs, although there is no bottom-border defined and anyway i don't want it to be there. check out the code, it's probably a mess so i'll be glad to have other comments as well if any1 has any. or in other words, **when i :hover .absection for some reason all .ability get bottom-border though it's not defined and shouldn't be there**. and as i said already, it happen only on 800*600 res on chrome, not in IE not in FF. here's the code

### HTML

```
`<div class="rightsection">
<h2 class="abilities">
<img src="logosmall.png" alt="" class="h2img"/>Some header</h2>
<div class="absection"> <div class="ability">
<img src="brainwave.svg" alt="some alt text">
<div class="closed-content">
<h2>HEADER</h2>
</div>
<div class="opened-content"><h2>HEADER</h2><p>Some more other content</p>
<div class="moreinfo">More</div></div>
</div>`
```

### CSS

```
`.abilities {
text-align: center;
}
.ability {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
background-color: #ffffff;
margin-top: 2vw;
margin-right: 0.5vw;
margin-left: 0.5vw;
width: 15vw;
height: 40vh;
text-align: center;
overflow: hidden;
}
.ability .closed-content h2 {
font-size: 2vw;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 3.5vh;
}
.ability .opened-content h2 {
font-size: 2vw;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 3.5vh;
}
.ability img {
z-index: 99;
width: 3.5vw;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 8vh;
left: 40%;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.ability .closed-content {
z-index: 1;
padding: 0;
background-color: #4D4343;
height: 100%;
width:100%;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
webkit-transition:all .5s ease-out;
moz-transition:all .5s ease-out;
transition:all .5s ease-out;
border-color: #E8C71A;
border-bottom-style:double;
border-width: 2vh;
}
.ability .opened-content {
z-index: 0;
text-align: center;
bottom: -73.5%;
position: absolute;
background-color: #000;
height:73.5%;
width:100%;
left:0;
border-bottom: 0.5vh solid white;
webkit-transition:all .5s ease-out;
moz-transition:all .5s ease-out;
transition:all .5s ease-out;
}
.ability .opened-content .moreinfo {
font-size: 1.2vw;
display: inline-block;
width: 40%;
margin-top: 25%;
border: 0.2vh solid #C7DDF1;
padding-top: 1.5vh;
padding-bottom: 1.5vh;
padding-left:1vh;
padding-right:1vh;
}`
```

### Hover effects and Media Queries

```
`.ability:hover img {
margin-top: 2vh;
}
.ability:hover .closed-content {
margin-top: -100%;
}
.ability:hover .opened-content {
margin-bottom: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
.ability:hover .closed-content {
margin-top: -132.5%;
}
.ability:hover .opened-content {
margin-bottom: 134%;
}
.ability {
margin-left: 0.3vw;
margin-right: 0.3vw;
}`
```

Yeah, sorry for the length. my first question though, so i'll hope u'll have the patience and help me, somehow o.0. Tnx a lot in advance... **J.o.**

Comment: You might check that all your `<div>` elements in your code sample are closed appropriately.

Comment: Seems to me that they are all closed. in the example above absection and rightsection aren't closed because i have 5 more div.ability inside absection which is the wrapper inside the rightsection. however i didn't set for absection any css rules...